# Failed to open VDI with new VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, vdi

I had to nuke my computer and reformat my hard drive because of a virus and i copied a snapshot of my VirtualBox VM. I made the mistake of not cloning and just copied the vdi file from the snapshot folder. Now i'm trying to create a new VM with the vdi file and get this error:

*Parent medium with UUID {178c8048-144b-4dcf-a1ad-b661402a911a} of the medium 'C:\Users\Ethan\VirtualBox VMs\aluminis{d1676259-419a-47cc-aac5-3f4c32a0e0da}.vdi' is not found in the media registry ('C:\Users\Ethan.VirtualBox\VirtualBox.xml'). 


Result Code:
E_FAIL (0x80004005)

Component: 
MediumWrap

Interface:
IMedium {ad47ad09-787b-44ab-b343-a082a3f2dfb1}

Callee: 
IVirtualBox {d0a0163f-e254-4e5b-a1f2-011cf991c38d}

Callee RC: VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80BB0001)*

I tried running internal commands to set the parent uuid: 
*VBoxManage.exe internalcommands sethdparentuuid "C:\Users\Ethan\VirtualBoxVMs\aluminis{d1676259-419a-47cc-aac5-3f4c32a0e0da}.vdi" {178c8048-144b-4dcf-a1ad-b661402a911a}*

I got the confirmation that the UUID had changed, but i'm still getting the error.

Comment: Can you create a new VM just like the old one and at the appropriate point, import the old VM. You may also be able to locate the old VM in the new folder and just open it.

Comment: That's what i meant when i said i created a vmi and tried using the vdi file, I stil get the same error.

Comment: Did you use exactly the same settings as the old one machine?  Memory, number of processors and so on?

Comment: Yes I did, but before I could even install the vm, virtualbox wouldn't let me even open the file

Comment: Something I used a long while back and may not work for you. Move the old machine out of the current VM folder to a safe neutral place.  Delete the new VM (that is why the safe backup). Restart the computer, make a new VM with a new file of the same name as the old VM.  Exit Virtual Box. Now replace the new (small) VM with the old VM file. Start Virtual Box.  Do you still get the same error?

Comment: Still get the same exact error

Comment: You will probably have to rebuild a new machine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105566/discussion-between-plee-and-john).

Comment: A snapshot is not a true copy.  So as I noted, you will probably have to start again